# If $U \times V$ is open, must $U$ and $V$ also be open?

Tags: general-topology

This is a repost of a question I posted earlier but was lacking detail. I hope this question is sufficiently detailed.

Let $X$ be a topological space. If $U$ and $V$ are open sets in $X$, then $U \times V$ is open in the product topology on $X \times X$. I am interested in the converse to this statement, that is if $U \times V$ is open in the product topology must $U$ and $V$ also be open?

I believe this should be true, since the product topology on $X \times X$ is defined as the collection
$$\{(A, B): A, B \subset X \text{ and open}\}$$
so the openness of $U$ and $V$ follow straight from the definition. Is this correct?

I also have two follow up questions. If these should be separate questions please let me know.

1. If this statement is true, it obviously is true for any finite product. Does it also hold in infinite products with the product topology? That is, an open set in the product topology contains finitely many components that are not equal to the whole space. Must all these sets be open if the product is open? What about in the box topology?
2. If we replace openness by closedness, does $U \times V$ being closed imply $U$ and $V$ must both be closed?

Comment: The projections $p_{X_j}(x_1,x_2)=x_j$ are open ($j=1,2$)

Comment: Note that $\pi[\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha\times V_\alpha] = \bigcup_\alpha \pi[U_\alpha\times V_\alpha] = \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$. So $\pi$ is an open map!

Comment: There's the case where $U$ is empty and $V$ isn't open, but if the product isn't empty then $U$ and $V$ are open.

Comment: The product topology is _not_ just the collection of $A\times B$ with $A,B$ open in the factors. (Also, better to write $A\times B$ than $(A,B)$, whose meaning is ambiguous in contemporary notation...) These are just a _basis_ for the product topology. :) But, still, the question is reasonable... :)

Comment: If $A\times B$ is closed and non-empty, take $y\in B$ then $A\times B\cap X\times \{y\} = A\times \{y\}$ is closed in $X\times \{y\}$, so $A$ is closed in $X$. Similarly, $B$ is closed. So this is true for closed sets also!

Answer (score 1):

The product topology on $X\times Y$ is not defined as the set of cartesian products of open subsets of X and open subsets of Y, because this family of subsets usually isn't closed under unions; for example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the union of $(0, 1)^2$ and $(-1, 0)^2$ isn't the product of two open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. This is why the product topology is the topology of which $\{A\times B:A⊂X, B⊂Y \text{ and open}\}$ is a basis.

If $U\times V$ is open in $X\times X$, let $x\in U$ and $y\in V$. Then, since $\{A\times B:A,B⊂X \text{ and open}\}$ is a basis and $(x, y)\in U\times V$, there are open subsets $U'$ and $V'$ of $X$ such that $(x, y)\in U'\times V' \subseteq U\times V$. Thus, $x\in U' \subseteq U$ and $y\in V' \subseteq V$, and since $U'$ and $V'$ are open, $x$ and $y$ are in the interior of $U$ and $V$, and therefore $U$ and $V$ are open because $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary elements of $U$ and $V$.

For the product topology of an infinite family of topological spaces, say $\prod_{\alpha\in I} X_\alpha$, the basis consists of the products $\prod_{\alpha\in I} A_\alpha$ such that $A_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha\in I$ and $A_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ for $\alpha\in I$. If $U_\alpha\subseteq X_\alpha$ and $\prod_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha$ is open, then if $x_\alpha\in U_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in I$, there is some $\prod_{\alpha\in I} U'_\alpha$ in the basis such that $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}\in\prod_{\alpha\in I} U'_\alpha\subseteq\prod_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha$, and since $U'_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$, we can finish the proof in the same way as before. For the box topology, the only difference is that we remove the condition for the basis that $A_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha\in I$, so the proof is the same.

If $U\times V$ is closed in $X\times X$, let $x\notin U$. For any $y\in V$, we have $(x, y)\in (X\times X)\setminus(U\times V)$, and since this set is open, there are open $U', V'\subseteq X$ such that $(x, y)\in U'\times V'\subseteq(X\times X)\setminus(U\times V)$. If we had that some $x'\in U'$ is in $U$, then $(x', y)\in U\times V$ and $(x', y)\in U'\times V' \subseteq(X\times X)\setminus(U\times V)$, a contradiction, so $U'\subseteq X\setminus U$. Hence, $X\setminus U$ is open and $U$ is closed. $V$ is closed by the same reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

If either set is empty, then $U\times V$ is empty and clopen regardless of whether the other set is open, closed, both, or neither. So assume both sets are nonempty.

If $U\times V$ is open, let $x\in U$ and $y\in V$, so $(x,y)\in U\times V$. As the set is open, we may choose open $A,B$ with $(x,y)\in A\times B\subseteq U\times V$. This yields $x\in A\subseteq U$ and $y\in B\subseteq V$, showing $U,V$ are open.

If $H\times L$ is closed, let $x\not\in H$ and $y\in L$. As the set is closed, we may choose open $A,B$ with $(x,y)\in A\times B$ and $(A\times B)\cap(H\times L)=\emptyset$. We claim $A\cap H=\emptyset$; this is witnessed by considering that any member $z\in A\cap H$ would yield $(z,y)\in (H\times L)\cap (A\times B)$, a contradiction. Then $A$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ missing $H$, showing $H$ is closed. A similar proof shows that $L$ is closed.